# how to search in a python list?

Tags: python

I'm facing a coding exercise but I can't solve the problem. That is subject:
A server experiences a sudden increase in lod at time t on metrics. Please chack the log and find out what process cause the increase.
There are eight processes A to H on the server, each process has four states: created, waiting, running, terminated.
When logging begins, all processes are in state terminated. In addition, the log has all process state changes up to timing t.

print the process name if only one processe is running at time t. print -1 if no process or multiple processes are running at time t.
exemple:
input:
15,
["0 A created",
"1 B created",
"10 A running",
"12 B waiting",
"13 B running",
"14 A waiting",
"17 B terminated",
"18 A terminated
]

output
"B"
this my code

```
# you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
# print("this is a debug message")

def solution(t, logs):
    new_logs = [item.split(' ') for item in logs ]
    temp = []
    final = []
    for item in new_logs:
        if item[2] == "running" and int(item[0]) <= t:
            temp.append(item[1])
        if item[2] == 'terminated' and item[1] in temp and int(item[0])> t:
            temp.remove(item[1])
            final.append(item[1])
    print(temp, final)
    if len(final) >= 2:
        return '-1'
    elif len(final) == 1:
        return str(final[0])
    else:
        return '-1'
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Why are checking states later than t in ```if item[2] == 'terminated' and item[1] in temp and int(item[0])> t:``` If I understand you correctly, you have to consider only state changes up to time t, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that probably this is an answer to an exercise, but you need to get used to use the appropriate data structure and **appropriate variable names** in your code. Don't use temp, final, etc. Use what the variable really mean to improve the code readability.

This is the sollution for your problem using dict:

```
def solution(t, logs):

    processes = {}

    new_logs = [item.split(' ') for item in logs ]

    # The logs provided by argument will always come in sorted by t?
    # If not, this solution requires it to be sorted
    # Best sort it yourself :)
    new_logs.sort(key=lambda item: int(item[0]))

    for item in new_logs:

        # if the time is greater than t, there is no need to analyze
        if int(item[0]) > t:
            continue
        
        processes[item[1]] = item[2]
    
    # uncomment this print to see the result dictionary
    # print(processes)

    processes_running = []
    for key, value in processes.items():
        if value == "running":
            processes_running.append(key)

    # Simplify the return as >= 2 and == 0 are the same
    if len(processes_running) == 1:
        return processes_running[0]
    else:
        return '-1'
```

Answer (score 1):

'*final*' is of no use to you due to it keeping processes terminated **after** time *t*, instead just use '*temp*'.

replace

```
if len(final) >= 2:
    return '-1'
elif len(final) == 1:
    return str(final[0])
else:
    return '-1'
```

with

```
if len(temp) == 1:
     return temp[0]
return '-1'
```